# kcachegrind having difficulties to link php xdebug calls

Tags: php, xdebug, kcachegrind

I'm using XDebug to generate profile repport. The profile are generated, but I'm unable to create a complete call graph using kcachegraph.

The XDebug config is:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /var/www/xdebug/
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t-%s
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

When I open the repport in kcachegrind, it seems to works, except that somt call seem in double, with one of the two having a location: (unknown).

Note that index.php only have 1 line of actual code, that is a require to the front controller. No autoloading at this stage of the execution, so I really can't figure out why I have 2 require::frontcontroller.php.

Here's a screenshot of 3 windows that might help you:
http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2226/kcachegrind123.png

Any clue on what could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this doubling also happen with a very simple script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally that's an XDebug problem with the profile.
It looks like Kcachegrind have changed their format, but XDebug have not been updated yet as per bug [#639](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=639).

This is now fixed for 2.1.1 and HEAD.

Comment: After compiling xdebug-2.1.2, it started working for me. So looks like it’s fixed now.

Comment: Instructions for compiling can be found here: [xdebug install](http://xdebug.org/docs/install)